# PHP mcrypt_create_iv returns question marks and incorrect length - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, salt, mcrypt

I'm trying to use `mcrypt_create_iv` to generate random salts. When I test to see if the salt is generated by echo'ing it out, it checks out but it isn't the required length which I pass as a parameter to it (32), instead its less than that.

When I store it in my database table however, it shows up as something like this `K??5P?M???4?o???"?0??`

I'm sure it's something to do with the database, but I tried to change the collation of it to correspond with the config settings of CI, which is utf8_general_ci, but it doesn't solve the problem, instead it generates a much smaller salt.

Does anyone know of what may be wrong? Thanks for any feedback/help

Comment: I just changed the char_set setting in CodeIgniters db config to latin1; it seems to have generated an okay salt, but I'll try and login and report back

Comment: PS: will there be any side effects to my other tables when I query the database now that I've set the char_set to be latin1?

Comment: Setting the charset to latin1 seems to have messed up the insertion of dates into the database. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `mcrypt_create_iv()` will return a binary string, containing \0 and other unreadable characters. Depending on how you want to use the salts, you first have to **encode** those byte strings, to an accepted alphabet. It is also possible to store binary strings in the database, but of course you will have a problem to display them.

Since salts are normally used for password storing, i would recommend to have a look at PHP's function [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), it will generate a salt automatically and includes it in the resulting hash-value, so you don't need a separate database field for the salt.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the password_hash function but it's only available in PHP5.5. I'm using WAMP, so it's not supported there yet for me to upgrade

Comment: What do you think of changing the column datatype in my database table to binary/varbinary, instead of varchar? Will it affect the encoding and decoding? I'm using the hash() function to encrypt/decrypt users passwords along with their salt

Comment: @a7omiton - There exists also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for the function password_hash(). If this is not an option, you could look at my [example code](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt), which generates a BCrypt salt. It depends of what you want to do with the salt, if you need it for BCrypt, then you should not store it separately in the database, just look at the example.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking through it right now. If I include the compatibility pack, will I be able to use it just like it is written in the PHP manual, or are there any considerations?

Comment: @a7omiton - The functions of the compatibility pack can be used exactly the same, they are written by the same author. Inside they are not exactly identical, but you will be able to remove the compatibility pack and your code should still work, they are "future proof".

Comment: Thanks man, but what do you mean by removing the compatibility pack and the code still working? Aren't you going to need it in the application i.e. to register new users maybe and encrypt their passwords?

Comment: @a7omiton - Sorry to be not precise, if you later switch to PHP 5.5 and this function is supported natively, then you can just remove the compatibility pack.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you very much for letting me know about this